# Inheriting class methods Javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Lets say I have two APIs and I would like to inherit classes from the first, but modify the response with .prototype.toJSON().

When I inherit from the first class, how can I inherit class methods as well.

An example

```
//file v1/models/users.js
var UserModel = function() {
  this.id = 0;
  this.firstName = '';
  this.lastName = '';
}

UserModel.find = function(q, callback) {
  //find any user that matches q and map them to UserModel
  if (err) return callback(err, null);
  callback(null, users);
}

module.exports = UserModel;
```

And the the next version

```
//file v2/models/users.js
var UserModel = require('../v1/models/users');

function UserModelV2() {
  UserModel.call(this);
}

UserModelV2 = Object.create(UserModel.prototype);
UserModelV2.prototype.constructor = UserModel;

UserModelV2.prototype.toJSON = function() {
    var obj = {};
    obj.firstName = 'foo';
    return obj;
}
module.exports = UserModelV2;
```

When I now try to call

```
var User = require('./v2/models/users');
User.find(1);
```

I get an error saying User.find does not exists.

I am aware I am only inheriting prototypal properties, but I cannot find an example of inheriting class methods anywhere.

Comment: `User.prototype.find` - a function's `.prototype` determines the prototype (`__proto__` property) of objects created by using that function as a constructor.

Comment: Just seen this, I think you mean `UserModelV2.prototype = Object.create(UserModel.prototype);`

Comment: @Thomas No. that is the correct use of `Object.create()`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus usually the constructor of a class is a function, not an instance of another class. Currently he's overwriting/replacing the constructor of `UserModelV2` with an instance of `UserModel`. And while you can still instantiate this construct with `Object.create()` you can not use the `new` keyword anymore. I'm not sure, that this is what he intended.

Comment: @Thomas I know. See my answer for the proper usage and note that I've removed the `Object.create` completely because the OP is using both techniques and doesn't need to.

Answer (score 3):

Don't add `find` directly onto `UserModel` because that causes the method to be added only to one instance.

Add it to the prototype:

```
UserModel.prototype.find = function(id) {
  //find the user by id and return 
}
```

Because all instances of `UserModel` will inherit from the prototype of your constructor function.

Then, your next version would inherit from the first like this:

```
// Constructor of sub-class
function UserModelV2() {
  // Call the prototype.constructor, not just .constructor
  UserModel.prototype.constructor.call(this);
}

// Perform inheritance
UserModelV2.prototype = new UserModel();

// Correct the constructor of the prototype
UserModelV2.prototype.constructor = UserModelV2;

// Extend the sub-class
UserModelV2.prototype.toJSON = function() {
    var obj = {};
    obj.firstName = 'foo';
    return obj;
}
```

By the way (and this could be why you got stuck on this), technically (and despite the `class` keyword), JavaScript does not have classes, it has prototypes and they are the basis for inheritance.

Comment: But then I would need to do var user = new UserModel(); user.find(id); every time. Or is there another way?

Comment: When you create a function to serve as your object basis, then you are making a constructor function and yes, that is how constructor functions are meant to be used. Your function indicates that you want individual instances because you are using `this`, which is exactly how you make instance properties. You can't have instance properties without constructing an instance (i.e. `new`).

Comment: Any other way to do what I would like to do? Maybe my example wasn't the best, because find can actually return more instances of User. I'll update my question.

Comment: @Ron Well, you have to decide whether you want/need instance properties or not (i.e. `this.id = 0;`). because if you have instance properties, you need to make individual instances.

Comment: Yes, I want instance properties, but I would like to share certain functions to update, delete, add and find users, but only the toJSON response needs to be different in V2.

Comment: @ron I have updated the answer to show how to use prototypes to perform inheritance. You will need to make distinct instances, but now, when you make an instance of V2, you will get the extended behavior.

Comment: `// Perform inheritance
UserModelV2.prototype = UserModel;` this ain't correct. That way, the instances of V2 don't inherit the methods from `UserModel`, but instead the static functions from that constructor. To be clear: `new UserModelV2().foo === UserModel.foo` not `UserModel.prototype.foo`. and `UserModelV2.prototype.constructor = UserModelV2` is now equivalent to `UserModel.constructor = UserModelV2`. Maybe you mean `UserModelV2.prototype = new UserModel();`? but then I'd prefer the `Object.create()` version

Comment: My mistake. Just forgot to set it to a new instance. The point is that the OP is trying to to use both techniques .

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can simply copy the methods over from `UserModel`

```
Object.assign(UserModelV2, UserModel);
```

Or you define that the `UserModelV2` function inherits its properties from the `UserModel` function instead of `Function.prototype` directly.

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(UserModelV2, UserModel);
```

Or you use the new `class` syntax and let that take care of this:

```
class UserModelV2 extends UserModel {
  toJSON(){
    return {firstName: 'foo'};    
  }
}
```

maybe in combination with a transpiler like babel, if you need backwards compatibility.

I'd encourage the last option. To me this seems like the cleanest approach and provides you with the ability to *not* use the transpiler. 
And it is semantically clear. Even the JS compiler can tell that you're not just arbitrarily messing around with the prototype of some function and may break something or do something "weird".

Comment: When using assign it finds the 'find' function, but also the toJSON of the old property is used.

Comment: there is no "old" `toJSON` method on your `UserModel`. And you have to assign the old properties **before** you attempt to overwrite them with new ones 